# What makes a React library require preact-compat?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I have noticed that certain libraries such as `classnames` are readily available in Preact but others like `styled-components` require `preact-compat`.

What makes a React library unsupported natively in preact that it requires the use of preact-compat?

Comment: Libraries that are built for `react`, usually have import statements related to `react` or its depedent libraires. To make use of the same library in `preact` without modification, `preact-compat` provides a `compatibility layer`. Libraries like `classnames` are not dependent on react and hence they don't require `preact-compat`. The [preact-compat github](https://github.com/developit/preact-compat) readme explains it quite well of how they achieve this compatibility layer.

Comment: Now that `preact-compat` (the separate shim repo) is no longer maintained as of PreactX (v10) & onward.  It is now part of the main Preact repo,  So you grab what you need from `preact/compat` (note the middle slash):

`import { PureComponent, memo, forwardRef, createPortal } from 'preact/compat'`

https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/switching-to-preact

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work on preact.

There are several APIs in `react` that are not needed for `preact`. But because existing third-party libraries have been developed for those APIs we published `preact-compat` which re-implements them on top of `preact`.

Some examples:

### `Children`-API:

This API is in particular interesting because it isn't needed at all for `preact`. With `preact` the `children` property is always an array.

```
// React
Children.forEach(props.children, child => ...);
Children.map(props.children, child => ...);
Children.count(props.children);

// Preact
props.children.forEach(child => ...);
props.children.map(child => ...);
props.children.length;
```

### `unmountComponentAtNode`:

This is another API that is not needed for `preact`, because we can simply unmount any tree by rendering `null`:

```
import { render } from "preact";
import App from "./app";

// Render App into dom
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

// Unmount tree
render(null, document.getElementById("root"));
```

If you want to drop a subtree instead of the root node you can do that via returning `null` from a component. Basically `null` is always treated as an *empty* value.

### `findDOMNode`:

```
// React
const element = React.findDOMNode(componentInstance);

// In Preact that's just a property
const element = componentInstance.base;
```

In our case this even works for function components. Note that in nearly all cases `ref`s are preferred over `findDOMNode`.

**Summary:** `preact-compat` contains mostly shims for third-party libraries expecting full API compatibility with `react`.