# What features do preact-compat provide that preact doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I built my web app using preact-compat. I tried swapping preact-compat for preact and it renders `<undefined></undefined>`. I read the preact-compat docs, but it doesn't say what it adds. I briefly went through the source code but it's not obvious what preact-compat adds.

Where can I find a list of differences between preact by itself and preact-compat?

Comment: preact-compat is just a compatibility layer allowing you to port React apps into preact. Its most common use case is that it allows you to use libraries and React built components in a preact project.

Comment: It's a project with insufficient documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific error, the cause was that `Preact.cloneElement` behaved differently for `preact` and `preact-compat`.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work on preact.

Just answered this question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773807/what-makes-a-react-library-require-preact-compat/54853288#54853288). The gist of it is that `preact-compat` mostly contains APIs which are not needed for `preact`. The main use case is to support existing third-party libraries that have been exclusively written for `react` and thus expect the full `react` API to be available.